# get bitmap from visible zoomed image android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an `Imageview` which is zoomed and rotated(I have used `multitouch zooming`). So how can i get bitmap of only visible content(I mean when i zoom the `image`, The part of the bitmap may go out of the screen. So, what i want is the `bitmap` that is visible on the screen). So is there any built in feature in `api` to create a small bitmap from a big one? or  Is there any function to crop the image using `x,y` coordinates? actually i want the zoomed or rotated part to go to the next `activity`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know all the scale and rotation-values, you can create a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) with those values, and apply them to your bitmap via the [Bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) method.
Example:

```
Bitmap original = ((BitmapDrawable) yourImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(degrees);
matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

A faster, but maybe not as pretty solution is to create a bitmap and draw your currently visible view onto that:

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourImageView.getWidth(), yourImageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
yourImageView.draw(c);
```

After which result should contain exactly what you see on screen.

Comment: Second solution is brilliant, worked, +1! Thou the first one did not work for me at all

Comment: What i can add is use bettermethod to conver drawable to bitmap -  public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }